# How/Why did Voq's voice change?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, klingon

[image]

When

> Ash Tyler

revealed himself as the Klingon Voq (STD:S01E11:The Wolf Inside) he began speaking with the voice of Voq (which we heard in earlier episodes).

> How did his vocal cords do that?   Wasn't he physically altered into a smaller, human form?
>  [image]

Comment: Perhaps rather than risk messing with his voicebox, Voq just practised really hard to sound human.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is never directly answered, but Shazad Latif, the actor who plays both Tyler and Voq, gives us a clue in [a 2018 interview](https://www.inverse.com/article/40200-shazad-latif-star-trek-discovery-ep-11-voq-tyler-spoilers). He mentions incorporating some of Voq's speech patterns into Tyler's voice, and comments (emphasis mine):

> **Latif:** I always wanted to have a hint of Voq in Tyler. So his American accent always has a kind of **pharyngealness** and I wanted to keep that up with the English when he's doing the Klingon. There’s so many different ways the **Klingon throat** would work. It’s got a bit of that Arabic sound.

Latif suggests that a large part of the Klingon voice is actually in [the throat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharynx), rather than in the vocal cords themselves. This isn't something human physiology necessarily struggles with<sup>1</sup>: as Latif notes, these [sorts of sounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttural) are common in human languages like Arabic, and are sometimes employed [in singing](http://www.voicesinc.org/how-to-build-pharyngeal-resonance-in-your-voice/).

If this is the case, then it's most likely that Voq is simply using the muscles he's used to speaking with, which produces a more guttural, Klingon-y sound than the muscles Tyler is used to speaking with. The vocal cords barely need to enter into it.

---

<sup>1</sup> This should be obvious, since humans are self-evidently capable of voicing Klingons in real life